# unable to ask user for repeated inputs for the problem set 1 mario in c programming language

Tags: c, cs50

i want to ask user infintely for a input between 1 and 8 till the user does that , the problem belongs to problem set 1 of mario in cs50 course , the task is doing fine except for again asking the user for input in case the input is below 1 or above 8 or non integer value . please suggest me for the same , thanks . here is my code 
Hi , i have been trying to take repeated inputs from the user for mario problem set 1 , whenever a user inputs below 1 or above 8 , but it does not asks again if the input is other than desired , stuck in it since yesterday , can anybody suggest how to repeatedly ask user for the input till the user enters a number between 1 and 8 , thanks , here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
int main(void)
{
int i , j , k , Height ;
Height = get_int("Enter desired pyramid height between 1 and 8: ");
while (!((Height<=8 && (Height>=1)))
{
    Height = get_int("Enter desired pyramid height between 1 and 8: ");
}
if (Height>0 && Height<9)
{
for (i=0;i<Height;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<(Height-1-i);j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(k=i+1;k>0;k--)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("  ");
    for(k=i+1;k>0;k--)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
}
```

Comment: `Height = -1;` then your loop will enter once for sure... you can also do a do/while loop.

Comment: i tried do/while loop , showing following errors in that :     timed out while waiting for program to exit

Answer (score 0):

It sort of works, there are some extra parens in there...

```
int get_int(char * _)
{
    return 8;
}
int main(void)
{
    int i , j , k , height ;
    height = -1;
    while (!(height<=8 && height>=1))
    {
        height = get_int("Enter desired pyramid height between 1 and 8: ");
    }
    if (height>0 && height<9) // this should always be true... remove it.
    {
        for (i=0;i<height;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<(height-1-i);j++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for(k=i+1;k>0;k--)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("  ");
            for(k=i+1;k>0;k--)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
           return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
       #  #
      ##  ##
     ###  ###
    ####  ####
   #####  #####
  ######  ######
 #######  #######
########  ########
```

Comment: when i enter your code it is showing me this error : ~/ $ make Untitled2 
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    Untitled2.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o Untitled2
Untitled2.c:5:5: error: conflicting types for 'get_int'
int get_int(char * _)
    ^
/usr/include/cs50.h:82:5: note: previous declaration is here
int get_int(const char *format, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
    ^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'Untitled2' failed
make: *** [Untitled2] Error 1
~/ $

Comment: I defined get_int function because you didn't provide it... remove the get_int

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int get_int(char * _)
{
    return 8;
}
int main(void)
{
    int i , j , k , height ;
    height = -1;
    while (!(height<=8 && height>=1))
    {
        height = get_int("Enter desired pyramid height between 1 and 8: ");
    }
    
        
                
 can you please correct my code and comment the right code, iam unable to understand, thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Would be more efficient and easier to read:

```
do {
    Height = get_int("Enter desired pyramid height between 1 and 8: ");
} while (Height<1 || Height>8);
```

Comment: it solved a part but showing following errors :     timed out while waiting for program to exit

Comment: That is completely your problem.